# Liquibase unable to authenticate user with @ and ! in password

Tags: postgresql, authentication, jdbc, liquibase

Using Liquibase 3.5.3 command line against PostgreSQL 9.6 I am unable to authenticate using users (e.g. postgres) with a password containing @ and ! characters.  If I change the password to remove them authentication works.  This occurs with other users as well. The password with @ and ! is correct and used in other applications.

I am using jdbc 4.2 driver from PostgreSQL with java 1.8 runtime.

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Is there anything unique about passwords when using jdbc and Liquibase?

Comment: Do you have it just when using Liquibase, or also when using JDBC directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to connect to oracle database using JDBC if password is having special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908610/not-able-to-connect-to-oracle-database-using-jdbc-if-password-is-having-special)

Comment: How are you connecting? Using spring liquibase integration or directly using liquibase itself? Show us your code.

Comment: This occurs just using the liquibase command line with username and password. There is no code and not using the jdbc driver directly.

Comment: I guess it's more likely to be your cli environment related than anything else. What os and shell are you using?

Comment: I was testing it out on windows.  I tried the password in quotations and not.  I'm sure it's an environment thing, but there's clearly a limitation that I couldn't find anywhere in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the command line, adding backslash for each special character will solve the problem.

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
  --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
  --classpath=\path\to\classes:jdbcdriver.jar \
  --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
  --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle" \
  --username=scott \
  --password=\!\@tiger\$\%\
  update
```

Or you can use a liquibase property file and put all parameters in that file. In this way, you can use original special characters in the password.

If you use build tool like Gradle or Ant, their reference block will help you skip this problem.

Comment: This would likely work, I only really needed to support the !.  I ended up switching to a different migration tool that didn't require escaping the password on command online.

Comment: @Corey Taylor, Do you mind to tell me what tool you switch to? Flyway?

Comment: Yes, I switched to Flyway.  It doesn't provide the extended format as liquibase, but it got me up and running initially.

Comment: @CoreyTaylor I really like the simplicity of Flyway. I'm waiting for more features to switch to that as well.