# SoapUI JDBC Connection Issue with the password

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection-string, soapui

So I am trying to connect to my database using a JDBC teststep in SoapUI.
I am using this connection string : 
jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/@12345@host:1521:SID

When I test this connection I get the error shown in the image [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN4fM.jpg)

After some researches, I found that the problem come from the '@' in the password (my password is '@12345').

I changed the password to '12345' and obviously it worked. 
Is there any solution for me to connect to my database without changing the password ?

Comment: As I have seen JDBC connection-string are URL format, try to put your password encoded just like this: : jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/%4012345@host:1521:SID. "%40" is "@" encoded.

Comment: I also have seen in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908610/not-able-to-connect-to-oracle-database-using-jdbc-if-password-is-having-special?rq=1 that you can escape specia vaues if you surround your password in double quotes with "\".

Comment: The two solutions don't work for me.
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/30/2/1532424595-connection-string.jpg

Comment: I quickly tried moving the username and password off to properties and building the JDBC URL with Groovy inside a dynamic property, but soapUI is still balking. Can you not just change the password?