# Solr database configuration: password with special characters

Tags: postgresql, solr, passwords

I'm trying to configure Solr to connect to a postgresql database. The problem is, the password contains special characters.

]T&FV{)pO-@lpMdD (this is an example of what am trying to use as password)

I tried escaping these characters with \ but it's not working.
I also tried with http encoding %5DT%26FV%7B%29pO-%40lpMdD but it's not working either.

Comment: You should be able to wrap your password in `"<password>"` - if you're going to use http encoding, it should be supplied at the end of the connection URL (i.e. `/database?password=%5DT...`

Comment: This actually worked ! Thanks.
Make your comment as a reply and i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr uses JDBC to connect to your database, so escaping the password would be the same as for regular JDBC strings.

You should be able to [wrap your password in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21913528/137650) - `"<password>"` - if you're going to use http encoding, it should be supplied at the end of the connection URL (i.e. `/database?password=%5DT...`.